# How can I hide a Woocommerce group product if any of its variable child products are out of stock?

Tags: php, woocommerce, product

Using Woocommerce, how can I hide a group of products if any of the products in that group is out of stock (the child products are variable products).

I want to add code in functions to accomplish this, but its not working:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'wc_product_display_css_overrides');

function wc_product_display_css_overrides() {
    echo "<style>.woocommerce-grouped-product-list{ display:none;}</style>";
}
```